# MySql order based on the value from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have got two tables `started_chats` and `chats` and i want to order `started_chats` based on the last chat sent.So here is my query

```
SELECT started_chats.* 
FROM started_chats 
WHERE User1='1' OR User2='1' 
INNER JOIN chats ON (chats.From_='1' OR chats.To_='1') 
AND (chats.To= started_chats.User1 OR
     chats.To= started_chats.User2)
ORDER BY chats.Date DESC
```

So first i select everything from `started_chats` where either User1 or User2 is equal to one.After that i join chats table to select the last chat sent either from 1 to other user(for example if User1 is 1 then i'm looking for chat from User1 to User2).But this query gives me this following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN chats ON (chats.From_='1' OR chats.To_='1') AND (chats.To= started_ch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your join after From

```
SELECT started_chats.* 
FROM started_chats 
INNER JOIN chats ON (chats.From_='1' OR chats.To_='1')
WHERE User1='1' OR User2='1' 
AND (chats.To= started_chats.User1 OR chats.To= started_chats.User2)
ORDER BY chats.Date DESC
```